# 127.0.0.1 slowness in django virtual environment running with vscode

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework, server

After connecting to the server built in awsec2 with a remote of vscode, the django virtual environment was run to make a connection of 127.0.0.1.
But its speed is too slow.
When you connect using Chrome, the loading is too slow, sometimes it's infinitely loaded, and sometimes there's content that hasn't been loaded even if it's marked.
There are even cases where only white pages are displayed.

I'm currently using a MAC.
Using a Windows laptop, connecting remotely to a remote server using vcode and then connecting to 127.0.0.1 will work fine

I've been looking for other posts, but none of them correspond to my issues.

I've tried many things.

1. Turn off the process that currently uses 8000 ports on the Mac (but it was not there)
2. Connect django to 8888 port or unused port and view it (this is the same error as well)

It used to work very well, but it doesn't work well at some point.

What should I do?

Addition:
If you look at the picture below, the contents of the web page are too slow to load or not at all.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4MUH.png)

Comment: wsgi is slow as compared to asgi, try to use asgi that's faster than wsgi, asgi can be faster and scale better than WSGI but only if you've written your application as async from the framework to the backend.

Comment: I am currently using WSGI.
However, there has been no problem developing local using WSGI for the past three months.
The problem has been happening since two days ago.

Comment: is there any package, or sertup  you did when you start serve or any script before loading server..?

Comment: run like this: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: Thank you for your opinion.
I tried running it at 0.0.0.0:8000, but it's still the same symptom.
I've updated the image that captured my symptoms in the post.